# How to change the mouse cursor into a custom one when working with Windows Forms applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, mouse-cursor

In a `UserControl` I want to change the mouse cursor from the arrow, to a hand icon.
What I currently do is this:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
```

This is very nice, it gives me a mouse cursor looking like this:

[image]

But here comes my problem... this shows a hand with a pointing finger.
What I need is a "grabbing" hand, more like this one:

[image]

How do I do this?, How can I load an icon file (.ico), a cursor file (.cur), or image file (.png), and use it as the mouse cursor?

Comment: The accepted answer works if the supplied file does not have color. In the case where you have color - you need to make use of the Windows API as described in my answer below.

Comment: @ Derek W: I did not realize that. The cursors I use indeed do not contain color info.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have a cursor file:

```
Cursor myCursor = new Cursor("myCursor.cur");
myControl.Cursor = myCursor;
```

otherwise you have to create one:

some more information about [custom cursors](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-how-to-use-custom-cursors)

Comment: Works perfectly! Also thanks for that link, I did not know that website.

Answer (score 5):

A caveat to using custom cursors with the WinForms `Cursor` class is that when using the stream, filename, and resource constructor overloads the supplied `.cur` file must be *black and white* in color.

Meaning that this will not work if the `.cur` files contains any colors besides black and white.

```
Cursor myCursor = new Cursor("myCursor.cur");
myControl.Cursor = myCursor;
```

There is a way around this limitation by using the Windows handle constructor overload:

Create the handle by using the Windows API:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string fileName);
```

Then pass it to the appropriate `Cursor` constructor like this:

```
IntPtr handle = LoadCursorFromFile("myCursor.cur");
Cursor myCursor = new Cursor(handle);
myControl.Cursor = myCursor;
```

I hope this prevents others from scratching their heads to an `ArgumentException` being thrown stating: `Image format is not valid. The image file may be corrupted.` when using the other `Cursor` constructor overloads with a `.cur` file that contains color.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried  `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor curs = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(file_name);`  ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this method. It's OK. This is my apply:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string fileName);
    Cursor myCursor;
    private void tsbtn_ZoomIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr handle = LoadCursorFromFile("view_zoom_in.cur");
        myCursor = new Cursor(handle);
        zg1.Cursor = myCursor;
    }
```