# How to change the cursor when a button is clicked

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I am developing a C++ MFC application using Visual Studio 2008. I have a button in my UI and when the user clicks the button I want to change the mouse pointer to a panning hand. How can I do this?

Comment: refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743644/how-to-change-the-mouse-cursor-into-a-custom-one-when-working-with-windows-forms

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SetCursor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When button is clicked, set `bool m_bHand` to true.

And in OnMouseMove()...

```
if (m_bHand == true)
{
    SetCursor(::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND));
}
else
{
    SetCursor(::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));
}
```

The 2nd parameter of LoadCursor can be your own ico resource ID.

Hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Finally I have found an answer. Double click on the button and I have copy the following code lines as the button function. Here IDC_CURSOR1 is the ID of the cursor which I have imported to my MFC Project. I have found cursors which are in C:\Windows\Cursors.

```
SetClassLong(m_hWnd,
          GCL_HCURSOR,
                     (LONG)LoadCursor(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),
             MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CURSOR1)));
```

Comment: This is a global solution (well, not really a solution) to a local problem. You want to change the cursor shape of a particular window class instance. Changing the window class (and thereby all window instances of that class) is going way too far. Call [SetCursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393.aspx) in the [WM_SETCURSOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382.aspx) handler.